# AWS policy StringNotLike not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set up a policy using `StringNotLike`, to prevent access to a particular bucket (named `secbucket`) and allows all other buckets. However whatever I put in the condition, it still allows access for all buckets.

```json
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
            "s3:prefix": [
                "secbucket",
                "secbucket/home",
                "secbucket/home/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify if I understand the `StringNotLike` with the Resource condition: If the `s3:prefix` does not match the conditions, it will allow access.

I am not sure what wrong with this policy. Please let me know what is wrong with this policy. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you try `secbucket`and `secbucket/*`as prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

The Bucket name is *not* part of the S3 prefix.

If you wish to create a policy that references the bucket name, you will need to do it as part of the ARN, eg:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::secbucket"
```

It appears your desire is to grant access to ALL buckets except `secbucket`. This can be done in two steps:

1. Grant access to all buckets by using an `Allow` statement
2. Deny access to `secbucket` by using a `Deny` statement

If you wish to secure `secbucket` from most of your users, an alternative method is to **put `secbucket` in a different AWS Account** and then use a Bucket Policy to only grant access to specific IAM entities. This is sometimes easier than denying access to lots of entities.